# (Pig-Latin converter read from .txt file) How to split contents of file into lines AND word by word? Python

Tags: python, list, split, line

I'm writing a piglatin converter in Python that takes a txt file and translates it line by line and outputs to another textfile in piglatin. It works properly except when I'm reading multiple lines, I need to have it output exactly the same.

code that splits the file between spaces

```
def getWords(vowels, file):

    listOfW = file.read().split()
    return listOfW
```

text inside notepad file:

```
if beast student 

away
```

Converted:  ['ifway', 'eastbay', 'tudentsay', 'awayway']

current output: (should be on two lines)

```
ifway eastbay tudentsay awayway
```

What it should look like:

```
ifway eastbay tudentsay 

awayway
```

getWords is just a function I used to get a list and then I convert them with another function

thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you already have such a function:

```
def convertToPigLatin(word):
    # returns converted string
```

You can open both your reading and writing file. Then iterate over each line of the in-file, split the line on whitespace, and convert each word in a list comprehension. Then you can write out that line to the out-file.

```
with open(infile, 'r') as fIn, open(outfile, 'w') as fOut:
    for line in fIn:
        convertedWords = [convertToPigLatin(word) for word in line.split()]
        fOut.write(' '.join(convertedWords) + '\n')
```

Comment: Yes, but for God's sake use `underscore_names` for functions and variables and `CamelCase` for classes.

Comment: @xj9 Whatever floats your boat :) (and follows your company's style guide!)